# For each loop loads last object only meteor

Tags: meteor

When we click on the family_type we need to get the materials.
In the material_list helper loads only the last object i need to load the every family based on materials needed.

```
{{#each search_family_list}}
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu active"><a href="#" id="{{ family_id }}" class="family_type"><img src="" />{{ description }}</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                        {{#each material_list}}
                                            {{#each this}}
                                            <li><a href="" id="{{ material_id }}">{{ description }}</a></li>
                                            {{/each}}
                                        {{/each}}

                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            {{/each}}
```

This my helper class

```
 Session.setDefault('materials_list',[]);

Template.header.events({
    "click .family_type": function (event, template)
    {

        Meteor.call('get_family_materials',event.target.id,function(err,result){
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                Session.set('materials_list',result);
            }
        });
    }
});

Template.header.helpers({
    material_list: function ()
    {
        var family_id = this.family_id;

        console.log(Session.get("materials_list"));
        return Session.get("materials_list");
    }
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than,

```
Session.set('materials_list',result);
```

do

```
var oldList = Session.get("materials_list");
Session.set('materials_list',oldList.push(result));
```

**Explanation**
`Session.set()` will set it to exactly what you tell it to.  When you set future values, it doesn't care what the previous value was.

Comment: Exception from Tracker recompute function: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.

Comment: That would likely be due to the {{#each this}} inside of your {{#each materials_list}}.  I'm guessing your materials_list is either an object or a string.  Which is it?

Comment: Please provide the chat

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `{{#each this}}`, and change the `{{#each material_list.id}}`

I don't really understand why are you using the `{{this}}`, but lets remove it an change the other `{{each material}}` tell me if works.

You can also remove the `3 {{each}}` you have into 1 `{{each}}` since the drop down menu can be outside.